# Jscript change css class VS Json

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, getelementbyid

I have this div on my html page

```
<div class="circle active" id="prg_inizio"> bla bla bla </div>
```

After Ajax call, I have a JSON result and I want to change the class name from "circle active" to "circle done".

I tried this but it seems doesn't work.

```
$("prg_inizio").removeClass("active"); 
$("prg_inizio").addClass("done");
```

JS Script GEt elements by id works perfectly.

```
document.getElementById("prg_inizio").classList.remove('active');
    document.getElementById("prg_inizio").classList.add('done');
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use `id` then `#` in front of selector and if `class` then `.` in front of selector.

You have to do it like

```
$("#prg_inizio").removeClass("active"); 
$("#prg_inizio").addClass("done");
```

```js
//$("#prg_inizio").removeClass("active");
//$("#prg_inizio").addClass("done");

document.getElementById("prg_inizio").classList.remove('active');
document.getElementById("prg_inizio").classList.add('done');
```

```css
.circle {
  padding: 10px;
}

.active {
  background: orange;
}

.done {
  background: green;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.5.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="circle active" id="prg_inizio"> bla bla bla </div>
```